# Can't use prepare() when using mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm tryign to create an object orientated approach to a project I'm working on for fun, but I'm having trouble getting my head around the idea of a database class. I'm getting the following error.

```
    Call to undefined method Database::prepare()
```

**Database Class**

```
class Database
{

    protected $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->createConnection();
    }

    private function createConnection()
    {

        $this->connection = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "test");
        if ($this->connection->connect_errno)
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->connection->connect_errno . ") " . $this->connection->connect_error;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Connected to database.<br />';
        }

    }
}

$db = new Database();
```

**UserActions Class**

```
class userActions
{

    protected $_db;
    protected $_username;
    protected $_password;
    protected $_auth;
    protected $tableName;
    function __construct($db, $username, $password, $auth)
    {
        $this->_db = $db;
        $this->_username = $username;
        $this->_password = $password;
        $this->_auth = $auth;

        $this->checkUserExists();
    }

    private function checkUserExists()
    {
        $query= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '{$this->tableName}' WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->username);
        $userNumber= $stmt->execute();
        echo $userNumber;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, could I do anything to improve the way I'm going about this task?

Comment: Your Database class doesn't have a prepare routine, not sure what else you expect....

Comment: @crowder http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: But you're (I assume) passing in YOUR Database class here (if not, why did you share that code)?

Comment: It seems like you're expecting your class to extend the `mysqli` class. But it just stores a `mysqli` object as a private variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following method to your class:

```
public function prepare($query) {
  return $this->connection->prepare($query);
}
```

You could define a magic method for your class that automatically passes any undefined method to the connection:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
  return call_user_func_array(array($this->connection, $name), $arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) But it seems a little long winded, am I coding this the right way? Or is there a better way to code the classes?

Comment: I've added a generic `__call()` method that allows you to use your class as a proxy for `mysqli`. Alternatively, you could define a public method that returns the connection, and then call mysqli methods directly on that.

Comment: I think the second option is best because I now have the problem of having to access 'bind_param'.

Comment: It's not clear what the point of your class is, then. Why not just call `mysqli_connect()` directly? The only thing your class does is hide the connection parameters.